# How to block in list members messages

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I wanted to do list of muted members and delete every message they write but I did something wrong because that command works at all members:

```
Muted_members = ["muted member id"]

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
for message.author in Muted_members:
...
```

Comment: `IndentationError` - and incomplete [mre]. Please [edit] and fix.Maybe read over [tour], [ask] and the 1st link.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace 
`for message.author in Muted_members:`
with
`if message.author in Muted_members:`
to check if the author is in the list and than execute your deletion and not execute your deletion code once for all muted members as you currently are doing.